# powershell constraints on arguments

Tags: powershell

I need a little help on how I can enforce the following constraints on the arguments to a powershell script. Can I specify these constraints with in the `param` section.

1. At least one argument constraint
2. At most one argument constraint

For example, (just an example, it's not what I am doing) to a script called `ReadPlainText.ps1`, I would like to give only either of the two arguments: `Lines` or `Chars`, but not both. The command `ReadPlainText.ps1 Sample.txt -Lines 20 -Chars 10` should result in an error. Similarly, the command `ReadPlainText.ps1 Sample.txt` should result in error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, in PSH V2, do this will parameter attributes and by putting the two parameters into different parameter sets.

A parameter set is a group of parameters that go together, a command can have multiple parameter sets and only one is available. Parameters not assigned to a parameter group are available across all parameters. This can be seen in the standard cmdlets (removing the common parameters):

```
PS> gcm -syn get-content

Get-Content [-Path]  …
Get-Content [-LiteralPath]  …
```

To achive this in a script or function:

- Add [`[CmdletBinding]`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347560.aspx) as the first non-comment. (A default parameter set can be specified here.)
- In the `param` block [decorate parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx) with the `Parameter` attribute to specify mandatory and the parameter set.

Thus:

```
[CmdletBinding]
param (
  [parameter(mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='lines')
  [int]$Lines,
  [parameter(mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='chars')
  [int]$|Chars
)
```

To access the parameter set in use `$PSCmdlet` which gives access to the same information available within cmdlets written C# or VB.

Comment: Please correct `mandator=$true` to `mandatory=$true`, i do not have edit rights

Comment: @oleschri Done. You could always suggest an edit, they get approved (or rejected) pretty quickly.

Comment: I know, but SO requires at least 6 changed characters to do so ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This Example ([Source: PowerShell Script – Marking a parameter as required/optional](http://jyothiregode.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/powershell-script-marking-a-parameter-as-requiredoptional/)) might help you ...

```
param(
      [string] $param1 = $(throw "required param"), #throw exception if no value provided.
      [string] $param2, #an optional parameter with no default value.
      [string] $param3 = "default value", #an optional parameter with a default value.
      [string] $param4 = $(Read-Host -prompt "param4 value"), #prompt user for value if none provided.
      [string] $param5 = $( if($thisinput -eq "somevalue") { "defaultvalue1" } else { "defaultvalue2" } ) #conditional default value  
      )
```

Comment: Valid maybe for V1. Don't use for V2, parameter sets are designed for this purpose.